# Submit operation fails due to DateTime precision

Tags: database, datetime, submit, ria, precision

RIA services does special things to populate properties that are generated by the server. One such value is the ModifiedDate field In my table, I have an identity column that is not the key. To get the database generated value, RIA queries for the record that it just inserted during submit, using the key values that it knows about for the row it just inserted. It handles this with the following query:

[WorkItemId], [WorkItemStatusCode], **[EffectiveDate]** is the key for the table.

exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[WorkItemHistory]
([WorkItemId], [WorkItemStatusCode], **[EffectiveDate],** [DateCreated], [DateModified], [ModifiedByUserId], [StatusReason], [Description], [MarketId])
values (@0, @1, **@2**, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, null)
select [iWorkItemHistoryId]
from [dbo].[WorkItemHistory]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [WorkItemId] = @0 and [WorkItemStatusCode] = @1 and **[EffectiveDate] = @2'**,N'@0 int,@1 varchar(25),@2 datetime2(7),@3 datetime2(7),@4 datetime2(7),@5 nvarchar(50),@6 nvarchar(100),@7 nvarchar(255)',@0=1,@1='CNCL',**@2='2011-01-24 19:32:27.5028893'**,@3='2011-01-24 11:32:27.5018892',@4='2011-01-24 11:32:27.5008891',@5=N'at',@6=N'NewDescription',@7=N'New WorkItem -1/19/2011'

**'2011-01-24 19:32:27.5028893** is not EXACTLY what gets stored in the db. It gets rounded off, so the ‘Where’ clause fails.

**'2011-01-24 19:32:27.503’** is in the db.

To address this, I could truncate the date to '2011-01-24 19:32:27’ OR I could take the Date out of the identity OR I could take the auto-increment counter off of iWorkItemHistoryId so it doesn't requery for the value during insert.

Thanks

Comment: do not use dates the way keys should be used, time is tricky stuff to join on in a reliable way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

When we normally store CreatedDate and ModifiedDate, the loss of precision is undetectable.

When we use a date in a primary key, however, the values are queried for precisely. DateTime2 should have been used to match the precision in .NET for DateTime.Now.

Switching to DateTime2 on the Key field solved the problem.

The loss of precision for date fields is usually undetected because we typically query for ranges of dates rather than a single date, as must be the case in a Key field.